# SQLAlchemy emitting cross join for no reason

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I had a query set up in SQLAlchemy which was running a bit slow, tried to optimize it. The result, for unknown reason, uses an implicit cross join, which is both significantly slower and comes up with entirely the wrong result. I’ve anonymized the table names and arguments but otherwise made no changes. Does anyone know where this is coming from?

To make it easier to find: The differences in new and old emitted SQL are that the new one has a longer SELECT and mentions all three tables in the WHERE before any JOINs.

Original code:

```
cust_name = u'Bob'
proj_name = u'job1'
item_color = u'blue'
query = (db.session.query(Item.name)
                       .join(Project, Customer)
                       .filter(Customer.name == cust_name,
                               Project.name == proj_name)
                       .distinct(Item.name))

# some conditionals determining last filter, resolving to this one:
query = query.filter(Item.color == item_color)

result = query.all()
```

Original emitted SQL as logged by flask_sqlalchemy.get_debug_queries:

```
QUERY: SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.name) items.name AS items_name
FROM items JOIN projects ON projects.id = items._project_id JOIN customers ON customers.id = projects._customer_id
WHERE customers.name = %(name_1)s AND projects.name = %(name_2)s AND items.color = %(color_1)s
Parameters: `{'name_2': u'job1', 'state_1': u'blue', 'name_1': u'Bob'}
```

New code:

```
cust_name = u'Bob'
proj_name = u'job1'
item_color = u'blue'
query = (db.session.query(Item)
                     .options(Load(Item).load_only('name', 'color'),
                                joinedload(Item.project, innerjoin=True).load_only('name').
                                joinedload(Project.customer, innerjoin=True).load_only('name'))
                     .filter(Customer.name == cust_name,
                                 Project.name == proj_name)
                     .distinct(Item.name))

# some conditionals determining last filter, resolving to this one:
query = query.filter(Item.color == item_color)

result = query.all()
```

New emitted SQL as logged by flask_sqlalchemy.get_debug_queries:

```
QUERY: SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.nygc_id) items.id AS items_id, items.name AS items_name, items.color AS items_color, items._project_id AS items__project_id, customers_1.id AS customers_1_id, customers_1.name AS customers_1_name, projects_1.id AS projects_1_id, projects_1.name AS projects_1_name
FROM customers, projects, items JOIN projects AS projects_1 ON projects_1.id = items._project_id JOIN customers AS customers_1 ON customers_1.id = projects_1._customer_id
WHERE customers.name = %(name_1)s AND projects.name = %(name_2)s AND items.color = %(color_1)s
Parameters: `{'state_1': u'blue', 'name_2': u'job1', 'name_1': u'Bob'}
```

In case it matters, the underlying database is PostgreSQL.

The original intent of the query only needs `Item.name`. The optimization attempt is looking less likely to actually be helpful the longer I think about it, but I still want to know where that cross-join came from in case it happens again somewhere that adding `joinedload`, `load_only`, etc. would actually help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because a `joinedload` is different from a `join`. The `joinedload`ed entities are effectively anonymous, and the later filters you applied refer to different instances of the same tables, so `customers` and `projects` gets joined in twice.

What you should do is to do a `join` as before, but use [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) to make your join look like `joinedload`.

```
query = (session.query(Item)
                .join(Item.project)
                .join(Project.customer)
                .options(Load(Item).load_only('name', 'color'),
                         Load(Item).contains_eager("project").load_only('name'),
                         Load(Item).contains_eager("project").contains_eager("customer").load_only('name'))
                .filter(Customer.name == cust_name,
                        Project.name == proj_name)
                .distinct(Item.name))
```

This gives you the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.name) customers.id AS customers_id, customers.name AS customers_name, projects.id AS projects_id, projects.name AS projects_name, items.id AS items_id, items.name AS items_name, items.color AS items_color 
FROM items JOIN projects ON projects.id = items._project_id JOIN customers ON customers.id = projects._customer_id 
WHERE customers.name = %(name_1)s AND projects.name = %(name_2)s AND items.color = %(color_1)s
```

Comment: That worked, yep. Good to know what was going on, even if it didn't turn out to be meaningfully different in speed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you're trying to do an inner join between the tables, and select only specific columns.

So I think you need to do something like:

```
cust_name = u'Bob'
proj_name = u'job1'
item_color = u'blue'
query = (db.session.query(Item.name)
                       .join(Project, Customer)
                       .filter(Customer.name == cust_name,
                               Project.name == proj_name)
                       .distinct(Item.name))

# Select the loaded columns
query = query.add_columns(Item.name, Item.color, Project.name, Customer.name)

# some conditionals determining last filter, resolving to this one:
query = query.filter(Item.color == item_color)

result = query.all()
```

FWIW I don't think that will bring any significant optimization to your query.

Comment: Although you're also selecting `.distinct(Item.name)`, so I guess, I'm wrong. Would help if you can explain what you want to optimize and how? :)

Comment: The only column I want is `Item.name`. The `load_only`s were an attempt to possibly speed up the query by ensuring that it didn't load anything extra. Looking at it further I'm less sure that it's actually an optimization, but I still want to know where this cross-join came from in case it ever comes up somewhere that the optimization would help. Editing question accordingly.